# JSON Serializer returns empty file

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have managed to create minimum reproducible example here:

```cs
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            Cache sc = new Cache();
            sc.Enabled = true;
            sc.Path = @"C:\File.txt";

            p.WriteToJsonFile("Cache.json", sc);
        }

        private void WriteToJsonFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
        {
            TextWriter writer = null;
            try
            {
                var contentsToWriteToFile = JsonSerializer.Serialize(objectToWrite);
                writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
                writer.Write(contentsToWriteToFile);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();
            }
        }

        internal class Cache
        {
            public string Path = string.Empty;
            public bool Enabled;
        }
    }
```

File `Cache.json` is created, but it only contains `{}`, which means that these properties were ignored and not saved. Perhaps something is wrong with the `WriteToJsonFile` method, but in some cases it seems to work. And it was approved answer in one of stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON serializers in C# tend to make use of *properties*, not *fields*.  These are just fields:

```
internal class Cache
{
    public string Path = string.Empty;
    public bool Enabled;
}
```

Make them properties:

```
internal class Cache
{
    public string Path { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```